# Comments aren't printing out on my Django Python site

Tags: python, django, comments

So I'm getting a bunch of comment objects in a dictionary called commentQuery.  However, the comments are not printing out on the actual post page.

Anyone see why?  Thanks!  (as you can see, I'm trying both the commentQueries and commentQuery options - neither are displaying on the page!)

views.py:

```
def comment(request):
username = request.POST.get("username")
itemID = request.POST.get("itemID")
comment = request.POST.get("comment")
new = Comment.objects.create(username = username, comment = comment, itemID = itemID)
new.save()
commentQuery = Comment.objects.all()
return render(request, "auctions/post.html", { "commentQuery": commentQueries})
```

post.html:

```
    <form name="comment"
          action="/comment"
          method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Enter Comment">
    <input autofocus class="form-control" type="hidden" name="itemID" value={{p.title}}{{p.price}}>
    <input autofocus class="form-control" type="hidden" name="username" value={{user.username}}>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Comment">
    {% endif %}
    </form>
{% for commentQuery in commentQueries %}
            <li>{{ commentQuery.comment }} by {{ commentQueries.username }}</li>
{% endfor %} 
        
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `{% for queries in commentQuery  %} {{ queries.comment }}` in the template. Is your comment ever saved? like did you ever manage to save a comment? checked in /admin for example?

Comment: I just figured out how to do the admin and yes, there are indeed comments being added to the table.  However, I'm not even getting a None type for my query so there's gotta be something wrong with my code.  I bet it's something minor I'm missing.  Any ideas?

Comment: seems like your comment function (in views.py) is never called. In your urls.py you link "   path("comment", views.post, name="comment")," to a function called "post" in your views.py. when you want to call the comment function, add another url which points to the right one, then you should get something printed in your terminal...

Answer (score 0):

I changed the path to path("comment", views.comment, name="comment"),"